# How to change "(can be pre-ordered)" to a custom text in WordPress Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

How to change "(can be pre-ordered)" to a custom text in WordPress Woocommerce or only appear when the stock is 0?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change this in WooCommerce > Settings > Pre-Orders > Add to Cart Button Text

Comment: I don t have these in my woocommerce :

enter image description here